# AS3: Display data(integer) from an swf to another swf through class

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a "score1.as" class in which it will access a data from an swf and display it into 
my "finalscore.fla"...I was able to pass and trace the data successfully into my "finalscore.fla"..But my problem is this: Though I was able to access the data by tracing it, I can't display it to my dynamic text...I thought by simply typing "`txtScore.text = ("Score: " + lol1.go() );`" would solve the problem but it didn't...Please help..Here's my code..bY the way, I'm using actionscript 3.0..

**score1.as:**

```
package  
{
  import flash.display.Loader;
  import flash.display.Sprite;
  import flash.events.Event;
  import flash.net.URLRequest;


public class score1 extends Sprite 
{
   private var loader:Loader;

public function Parent() 
{

    loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
    loader.load(new URLRequest("savescore.swf"));//This is the swf where in the data came from
}

public function onLoaded(e:Event):void 
{

    trace(loader.content['currentScore']);
}

public function go():int{

    return loader.content['currentScore'];//This is the data being accessed
}


}
}
```

**finalscore.fla:**

```
var lol1:score1 = new score1();


txtScore.text = ("Score: " + lol1.go() ); // This is where I can't display the data


lol1.Parent();//I successfully traced the data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your embedded fonts.  You are likely only embedding the characters from the font that were present at compile time.  For example, if you have a textfield with "Hello World!", and you wanted to do `textfield.text = "Jiggly Jello Lord!"`  would display as "l ello ord", because only those characters were present in the textfield during compile.

[image]

---

### Edit:

I took a closer look at your code.  You need to call `Parent()` before you can get your content.  In fact, rename it to be the constructor, and you should be good.

```
package {
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;

    public class score1 extends Sprite {
        public var loader:Loader;

        public function score1() {
            // You need to run this code as your constructor.
            loader = new Loader();
            loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
            loader.load(new URLRequest("savescore.swf"));
        }

        public function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
            trace(loader.content['currentScore']);
        }

        public function go():int {
            return loader.content['currentScore'];
        }
    }
}
```

You'd also want to wait for your content to be loaded before accessing the data.  For this, you'd need to wait for your `onLoaded` to fire before trying `txtScore.text = ("Score: " + lol1.go() );`

---

### Edit 2

`onLoaded` is how you know if it runs.  It gets called when `Event.COMPLETE` fires.  By the same extension, just register for that event from outside your class, or fire an event, or any other solution that completes after the data is loaded.

**finalscore.fla:**

```
var lol1:score1 = new score1();
lol1.loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, scoreReady);

function scoreReady(e:Event):void {
    txtScore.text = "Score:" + lol1.go();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I'll give it a try..so the codes have no problem?

Comment: Thanks..I just did what you did on edit..I just replaced the "Parent" by "score1" in the score1.as and also replaced "lol1.Parent();" to "lol1.score1();" in the finalscore.fla...But I still got an error..It says: call to possibly undefined method score1 through a reference with static type score1. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: You don't call the constructor directly.  It gets called (automatically) when you instantiate a class.  So just do `var lol1:score1 = new score1();` and after the `onLoaded()` runs, you can set the `txtScore.text` value.

Comment: Thanks..How do I know if the onLoaded() runs? Am I going to trace it?

Comment: Wow!..You just saved me..Thank you very much..It works..Hope you continue answering questions from noob coders like me..